# normalize Euclidean distance - python

Tags: python, numpy, euclidean-distance

```
def euclidean_distance(n):
    L = np.linalg.cholesky( [[1.0, 0.60], [0.60, 1.0]])
    
    uncorrelated = np.random.standard_normal((2, n))
    correlated = np.dot(L, uncorrelated)
        
    A = correlated[0]
    B = correlated[1]
    
    v = np.linalg.norm(A-B)
        
    return v

v50 = euclidean_distance(50)
v1000 = euclidean_distance(1000)
```

The euclidean distance is larger the more data points I use in the computation. How can I normalize the distances so that I can compare similarity between `v50` and `v1000`?

Comment: This probably belongs on [stats.se] since you aren't asking about _programming_ the method, you're asking about the method itself

Answer (score 1):

you can normalize the distances by dividing them by the square root of the number of data points used in each computation. try this:

```
v = np.linalg.norm(A-B) / np.sqrt(n)
```